# Accessing variable inside method, python tkinter

Tags: python, class, methods, tkinter

I'd like to preface by saying I've read the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html) and I guess I'm not sure how to use the provided information, or I'm just not capable of seeing the difference between the provided code and my code. I've also searched on google for relevant issues to no avail. I'm currently following [this tutorial](http://sebsauvage.net/python/gui/#class)

I've made a tkinter window for a simple program I'm working on, but now I'm trying to put it in a class and everything's going downhill. The basic structure of the code in question is as follows:

```
from tkinter import *

class WindowManager(Tk):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        Tk.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        # Place items for console log
        self.initialize()

    def initialize(self):
        self.grid()
        self.text_item = Text(self, bd=0, bg="black", fg="white", height="15", width="56", )
        self.text_item.grid(column=0, row=0)

    def access_text(app):
        app.initialize.text_item.delete('1.0', END)


def main():
    app = WindowManager(None)
    app.title("Main Window")
    app.geometry("400x250")
    app.resizable(0, 0)
    app.mainloop()

    access_text(app)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Now this is just the basic structure of the code in question, and everything that's relevant.

**An error is being thrown when the window closes saying "'function' object has no attribute 'text_item'"**

My best guess is that it's trying to do something with functions in general and not accessing the code found within the function in question, but I'm not sure what the proper way to access this variable is.

Any help or clarification would be much appreciated. Thank you for your time.

Comment: I ran it in python 3.5.2, removing the bg, fg and font that are not defined in your example in the Text creation and it runs without error.  `access_window()` is not called. Why does it have `.initialize()` ? You don't want to create a new text widget, do you?

Comment: On the access_window() part, I just forgot to put it in the main function of my example, I'll fix that right away.
And yes, I'm trying to create a new text widget to be placed on initialization, and my issue is accessing said widget outside of the class

Comment: There is at least one error in `access_window()`, you are calling an instance method with the class instead of an instance.

Comment: Can you update the code into an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that throws the error?

Comment: The code has changed since my last comment. It now produces another error because `access_window()` is called after the mainloop exited, which is meaningless. There is no need to call  `.initialize()` more than once.

Comment: It's unclear what you are trying to achieve with `app.initialize.console_log.delete('1.0', END)` line. Maybe it's meant to be `app.text_item.delete('1.0', END)` line?

Comment: Also, can you please fix your code indentation. `class WindowManager(Tk):` and following should be indented as well.

Comment: The console_log is represented by text_item in my example, and I forgot to switch the name when creating my example.
The line indentation should be fixed.
I'm trying to get the variable from inside app.initialize, thank y'all for being understanding. I understand I've made quite a few errors that make it difficult to help

Comment: The `text_item` variable is not a local variable in `initialize()`, it is an attribute of the `app` instance. You can access it directly: `app.text_item`.

Comment: @Gribouillis, ...and there's no point to do this after `mainloop`.

Comment: @Gribouillis AttributeError: '_tkinter.tkapp' object has no attribute 'console_log' is raised when I use app.text_item

Comment: @CommonSense Before I moved tkinter into a class it worked fine outside of the mainloop

Comment: Apparently, you wrote `app.console_log` again instead of `app.text_item`.

Comment: ...Damn it. Thank you all for your help and bearing with my poor attention to detail. I'm going to close the thread now and mark it as answered. I apologize for any time wasted

Answer (score 0):

My issue was I was trying to access the variable from the method when it was a local variable in the class

Instead of `app.initialize.text_item` I should have just had `app.text_item`.

Credit to @Gribouillis